# Django - manytomany field dependent on other manytomany field

Tags: django

I have Contents App which has two ManyToMany fields, `category` and `sub_category`.  `sub_category` is dependent on `category`.

```
class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('categories.Category', null=True, blank=True)
    sub_category = models.ManyToManyField('categories.SubCategory', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the Categories app, i have the `Category` and `SubCategory` class.  In `SubCategory` there is the column: `category_id`, which is a foreign key and defines which category the sub_category is under.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

In Contents App what i want is only show sub categories for the categories selected.  How do i do this?

Comment: can you update question with your views where you want to show sub categories of categories ?

Comment: i have default views.py that was generated for Contents app

Comment: where you want to show sub categories of categories ?

Comment: user will be able to select category and sub categories on the contents app.  They will be select dropdown with multiple options.  This is default for ManytoMany field.  Here is example(see Alternatives):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Uy1.png